# Get Drive Size in Java 5

Tags: java, size, drive

I want to get the size of a drive (or UNC path pointing to a partition would be nice, but not required), as well as free space for said drive (or UNC path).  This doesn't need to work cross platform; only in Windows.

I know it's easy to do in Java 6, but that's not an option; I'm stuck with Java 5.

I can get the free space available by doing:

> cmd.exe /c Z:\ /-c
>
> or
>
> cmd.exe /c \\server\share /-c

and just parsing out the resulting bytes free.  However I can't seem to find a way to get the total drive size.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use fsutil on the command line.  It returns something like this:

```
D:\>fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo c:
NTFS Volume Serial Number :       0xd49cf9cf9cf9ac5c
Version :                         3.1
Number Sectors :                  0x0000000004a813ff
Total Clusters :                  0x000000000095027f
Free Clusters  :                  0x00000000002392f5
Total Reserved :                  0x0000000000000490
Bytes Per Sector  :               512
Bytes Per Cluster :               4096
Bytes Per FileRecord Segment    : 1024
Clusters Per FileRecord Segment : 0
Mft Valid Data Length :           0x000000000e70c000
Mft Start Lcn  :                  0x00000000000c0000
Mft2 Start Lcn :                  0x0000000000000010
Mft Zone Start :                  0x0000000000624ea0
Mft Zone End   :                  0x0000000000643da0
```

Multipy your number of sectors times the bytes per sector to get your size.

Comment: this won't work for network drives, but i think this is as good as it's going to get

Answer (score 1):

You could do this pretty easily using a JNI call if you are comfortable with that...

If you want a pre-packaged library that you can use with JDK1.5, take a look at the [Apache FileSystemUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/FileSystemUtils.html)

This just wraps the system call that you describe, but at least it's a standard library that you can use until you are able to use 1.6.

Comment: Actually, FileSystemUtils goes via the command line, using the dir command. And it only supports free size, not total size.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [SIGAR](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) library, which gives you native access on many platforms.